# "first use" error when change the code in lex file

Tags: yacc, lex

Given a `.l` file like this:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[ \t\n]
"if" return IF_TOKEN ;
"while" return ELSE_TOKEN ;

. yyerror("Invalid Character");

%%

int yywrap(void){
    return 1;
}
```

and a `.y` file like this:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%token IF_TOKEN ELSE_TOKEN MINUS_TOKEN DIGIT_TOKEN

%%
program :expr {printf("program Accepted!!!");};
expr : IF_TOKEN | DIGIT_TOKEN ;
%%
void yyerror(char *s){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(){
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

I use these 3 commands to compile these 2 files (my lex file named p.l and my yacc file named p.y):

```
flex p.l
yacc -d p.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c
```

It is compiled with no error. But when I changed "return ELSE_TOKEN" to "return WHILE_TOKEN", I got this error and got no output file:

```
p.l: In function ‘yylex’:
p.l:10:8: error: ‘WHILE_TOKEN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
"while" return WHILE_TOKEN ;
        ^
p.l:10:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Also when I change "while" to "else" and add a new rule like:

```
"for" return FOR_TOKEN ;
```

I get the same error. How can I correct the code to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add:

```
%token WHILE_TOKEN FOR_TOKEN
```

to the grammar, so the header didn't contain a definition for `WHILE_TOKEN` or `FOR_TOKEN`, so the compilation of the lexical analyzer failed.